# PHP & MySQL - Most efficient way to display last ten entries in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a database, and I would like to display the last ten entries.

So far I have tried several ways but run into a couple of issues. I have tried using a for-loop starting at the row count for the database and linking that to the ID, but then of course should I delete an entry the iterations will have data missing. For example if I have deleted lots of entries and have the first entry start at id 20 then if there are only 10 rows it will look to display 10 to 1, which don't exist.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I little confuse, what do you mean by `last ten entries in a database? ` Normally, is last ten entries in a table. So, are you trying to look for ten tables has just been updated?

Answer (score 2):

You could try, depending on your implementation,

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE conditions ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: How would you use this to display the 10 entries? Would you iterate through this?

Comment: Assuming you have PHP set to return an array, yes.

Comment: So, very basic question here, but how would the new for-loop look ideally?

Comment: It depends on your database functions. If you're using `mysql_*`, which you shouldn't be, you'll use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { // do things with $row }`. If you're using PDO, you'll use `foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) { // do things with $row }`. Dunno about MySQLi.

Comment: *shouldn't be using `my_sql*`

Comment: @mark The `mysql_*` class of functions (e.g. `mysql_query`, `mysql_real_escape_string`) have been deprecated in favor of [MySQLi](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mysql_connect("localhost","usernm","pwd");
mysql_select_db("database");
$rs=mysql_query("SELECT id,col1,col2,coln FROM table_name WHERE condt ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=  mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```